# knockout.js virtual template binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am trying to implement tree structure using combination of knockout.js and jquery-mobile-ui collapsible-set. Since tree can be substantially large, I am using 'if' bindings to prevent data processing before tree node is expanded. When tree node is expanded I want to use virtual knockout binding, using normal  binding produces side effects in jquery-mobile-ui. When I expand node I can see

```
<!-- ko data-bind= template: { name: 'treeTemplate', foreach: $parent.Children } --><!-- /ko -->
```

I don't get any binding errors, however template is not being rendered. I can see that element is bound by calling

```
ko.contextFor($('.sss').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8;})[0]);
```

and it has $parent.Children not empty (Screenshot). 
[image]
**Question:** Is virtual template binding is supported in knockout.js and if it is what am I doing wrong? Any help or ideas how to debug current situation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Skip the `data-bind`= in your virtual element, just do

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'treeTemplate', foreach: $parent.Children } --><!-- /ko -->
```

Just a quick tip for reading up on debugging: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html

Comment: Best tip you can pick up from that article is the `uniqueName` binding.